# How do I stop div from getting bigger when zooming/dezooming?

Tags: html, css, web, position

When I zoom, the div gets bigger, when I dezoom, it gets smaller. It also changes place and it's a pain.

html:

```
<div id="update-logs">
    <h2>Update Logs</h2>
    <div id="log-text">
        <ul id="update-list">
            <li id="update-1">Update 1</li>
            <li id="update-2">Update 2</li>
            <li id="update-3">Update 3</li>
            <li id="update-4">Update 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   
</div>
```

css:

```
#update-logs {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:200px;
    background-color:#1b1b1b;
    margin-right:1200px;
    height:350px;
    border-radius:5px;;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#0e0e0e;
    border-width:15px;
    text-align:center;
    color:rgb(201, 201, 201);
    
}
```

I tried changing the position to any types. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Add width with a fixed value to the div. Ex: `width: 350px;` or `width: 20rem;`. This way, the div will stay at 350px / 20rem width no matter what the screen size is.

You can also use percentages to give it width based on the proportion of screen size. Ex: `width: 50%;`. This will keep the div width half of the screen size.